# NodeJS async foreachlimit on stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, stream

I am streaming in a large response dataset from an http request.  I am taking the response and parsing out url's that need to be fetched for subsequent data.  When I do this without any control flow it just ends up crashing. How would I use a function like async's foreachlimit but with an iterator being a stream rather than an actual array?  Am I thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the concept of "pausing" a stream and this served me well.

stream.pause()
stream.resume()